# Getting error An invalid dn syntax has been specified with AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net, authentication, active-directory, ldap, openldap

My configuration is as follows:

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="ADService" connectionString="LDAP://myserver.com:636/ou=people,dc=mysite,dc=com" />
</connectionStrings>

<membership defaultProvider="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
      connectionStringName="ADService"
      attributeMapUsername="uid"
      attributeMapEmail="mail"
      connectionProtection="Secure"
   />
```

I have verified the connection string it works and returns the objects with uid=xxx . But with ASP.net I am recieving error

> Parser Error Message: An invalid dn syntax has been specified.

My Ldap server support anonymous binding. What am i doing wrong ? The server I am connecting to is not AD but an OpenLDAP 3.0 .

Comment: The OpenLDAP logs should have a record of the DN that submitted for the request. What is that DN when the server rejects the request?

Comment: I do not have admin access to server. I can only use for authentication.

Comment: Is it possible to get an LDAP administrator to examine the logs and tell what the DN was when the server rejected the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an LDAP configuration issue. It required an SSL connection which I was not doing. It needed AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer | AuthenticationTypes.FastBind in the connection option.

On the other note, this built in api only works for AD so I had to write my own.

Answer (score 0):

When do you get the error? i.e. What part of your code? Invalid dn syntax can be thrown for a couple of reasons: like problem with the connection string or invalid characters like comma in a property while you are retrieving it.

Btw: `attributeMapUsername="uid"`? Are you sure about this? Why not `attributeMapUsername="userPrincipalName"`? or `attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"`?

Comment: error happens when the login page is submitted.  uid is used because that is the object for user name